# Блокировка входящего трафика на определенный IP сервера

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, firewall

Здравствуйте, есть такой вопрос, прочитал очень много документации, но не нашёл того, что искал.

- Как правильно заблокировать входящий трафик на 80 порт к определенному IP сервера (адрес работает, например на интерфейсе eth0:1)
- Правило для блокировки всех входящих http запросов на 80 порт, у которых юзер агент пуст (в логах nginx выглядит как "-")

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, чем вам пустой юзер-агент не угодил?

Comment: Кстати, фильтрацию юзер-агента фаервол не может, это про nginx, рекомендую вынести в отдельный вопрос

Comment: Пытаются зафлудить 80 порт GET запросами.
Мешаю видимо кому-то своей деятельностью (хостинг).

Answer (score 0):

1. `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d _ТУТ_IP_ADDRESS_ -j DROP`
2. `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" -j DROP` ((c) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209551/how-can-i-block-some-special-user-agents-via-iptables) , [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/690870/iptables-block-user-agent))

Лично я бы анализировал трафик и блокировал по каким-то иным паттернам, в крайнем случае - гео-блокировка.

Comment: 1ое правило блокирует лишь доступ одного адреса к 80 порту
2ое- блокирует не пустой user-agent 
:)

Comment: 1. Нет. 2. Да. (Для второго показал просто пример и добавил вторую ссылку пройдя по которой возможно составить правило нужное Вам)

Comment: Анализировать трафик у меня нет возможности.
Бомбят с ботнета и с пустым юзер-агентом, обыные GET.
Остальные гадости типа UDP блокируется на уровне ДЦ

Comment: @АндрейВоронов подпишут юзерагент гугл-хрома и продолжат бомбить)

Comment: Для начала пусть догадаются в чем проблема блокировки)

Comment: @АндрейВоронов первое правило блокирует запросы приходящие на определённое сочетание dst-ip и dst-port, это как-раз то о чём вы спрашивали